# Splash Screen in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I am creating a application which loads  a dynamic UI. My problem is when i started one activity to another activity, the second Activity showing Black Screen because of Dynamic loading UI.

I have the following Question: Can i start one activity to run in Background(like service) of another Activity(like Splash Screen).

***Example*** Activity A(Splash Screen) starts Activity B(Main activity). Activity B takes some time to load its dynamic UI. After finishing its load, i want to show Activity B. Until it is finished loading, I would like Activity A to be running in the foreground and B running in Background.

I have tried Threads, Timer and AsyncTasks. All start the Activity B immediately.. please share your Ideas.

Comment: Is it possible to create the data statically somewhere and do the initialization?  Or have it loaded semi globally?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have kind of a splash screen or global overlay while the data are loading in an AsyncTask.

```
ActivityA -> launches -> ActivityB
ActivityB -> displays SplashScreen
          -> run AsyncTask -> populated ActivityB
```

Read [Android SplashScreens Done Right](http://blog.iangclifton.com/2011/01/01/android-splash-screens-done-right/)

So you don't need ActivityB to be in the background. You just:

- present a waiting screen / overlay / whatever **above** ActivityB
- ActivityB gets populated in real time